# Delphi remap key to multi characters

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, keyboard-events, vcl

I want that when I press a `M` or `m` character, `000000` gets input on a specific `TEdit` box:

```
procedure Tfrm.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char) ;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  if Key in ['m'] + ['M'] then Key := '0';
end;
```

With this code, I can just remap 'M' key to single character.  How can I remap 'M' to multiple characters for a `TEdit` box?

Comment: Why you do not use the `TEdit` events for that ?

Comment: Do you want to input `000000` to a `TEdit` when *any* control receives `M`/`m`?  Or only when received by the same `TEdit`? Do you want the `M`/`m` to still be processed by the control that receives it, or do you want to discard it?

Comment: i want when received m/M, input 000000 to a Tedit,for example when input 1m to Tedit, Tedit looks value 1000000 ( m means million). i didnt use m char in TEdit component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `OnKeyPress` event of the `TEdit` itself, not the `OnKeyPress` event of the parent `TForm`.  Set the `Key` parameter to #0 to swallow it, and then insert 6 individual `'0'` characters into the `TEdit`:

```
procedure Tfrm.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  if Key in ['m', 'M'] then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    for I := 1 to 6 do
      Edit1.Perform(WM_CHAR, Ord('0'), $80000001);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure Tfrm.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key in ['m', 'M'] then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    Edit1.SelText := '000000';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why not use `Edit1.SelText := '000000'` (or, even better, `TEdit(Sender).SelText := '000000'`)?

Answer (score 2):

you can not "remap" indeed

but you can kill that specific char (setting it to #0) and inject the needed zeroes using standard Windows Messaging API (SendMessage, not PostMessage)

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276.aspx
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/TControlPerform_(Delphi)
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Perform

Something along those lines:

```
procedure Tfrm.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var i : integer;
begin
    if ActiveControl = Edit1 then
      if Key in ['m'] + ['M'] then begin 
         Key := #0; // zero-out the real key so it would not be handled by the editbox
         for i := 1 to 6 do
             ActiveControl.Perform( WM_CHAR, Ord( '0' ), $80000001);
             // or you may reference the specific editbox directly
             //  like Edit1.Perform(....);
      end;
end;
```

This would also require setting the form to intercept the keys of its controls.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.KeyPreview

This makes sense if you want to hijack several editboxes at once. If not you better you the events of the editbox itself, not ones of the form.

```
procedure Tfrm.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var i : integer;
begin
   if Key in ['m'] + ['M'] then begin 
      Key := ^@; // zero-out the real key so it would not be handled by the editbox
      for i := 1 to 6 do
          Edit1.Perform( WM_CHAR, Ord( '0' ), $80000001);
          // or you may reference the specific editbox directly
          //  like Edit1.Perform(....);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: If you have any component (TEdit,TButton,TMemo,etc.) on the `Tfrm` Form it will not run through the `FormKeyPress` Event !!

Comment: @moskito-x there is KeysPreview property. However I try to stay close to the topicstarter code (so it would be most clear what I added to the 'boilerplate' of his making) trusting his "i can just remap 'M' key to single character with this code" assessment. In general I agree that to make the code stable either the check "which editbox it is exactly" should be added or the editbox's own events be used.

Comment: PS. I most probably would be offline for next days to come, so if the question would get extended/morphed by new details/problem it would be okay for others to add their answers or to mods for modify this answer of mine.

Comment: @Arioch'The: If I really wanted to nitpick, I would also change `['m'] + ['M']` to `['m', 'M']`, and move the logic to the `TEdit`'s own `OnKeyPress` event instead of the Form's event. Especially since in the *Form's* event, the `Sender` is the Form itself, not the control that received the `Key`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the first one would also be nitpicking, since it is also "changing" the constant into itself. Latter ones would make code different thus would be real edits.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Based on the OP's latest comment, using the Form's `KeyPreview` functionality is the wrong approach. Use the `TEdit`'s own `OnKeyPress` event instead (using `ActiveControl` in the Form's event is the same thing as using the `TEdit`'s own event). And BTW, I just tried your code and it does not actually insert the new characters, because your parameters for `WM_CHAR` are backwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to equip all `TEdits` with this behavior, then set all other `TEdits KeyPress` events to `Edit1KeyPress`

```
procedure Tfrm.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
xEdit: TEdit;
begin
if Key in ['m','M'] then begin
       Key := #0;
       xEdit := Sender as TEdit;
       xEdit.Text := xEdit.Text +'000000';
    end;
end;
```

Or short version

```
procedure Tfrm.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
if Key in ['m','M'] then begin
   Key := #0;
   TEdit(Sender).Text := TEdit(Sender).Text+'000000';
end;
end;
```

Comment: in such a situation using many per-editor events might really be not any better than using the form's event. Though might be better if the form's WM-related events are already overloaded with long and complex logic, but that is hardly the case here

Comment: @Arioch'The : From your code : `if ActiveControl = Edit1 then` you have to change always `= Edit1` to the TEdits name.

Comment: In case of several boxes it would become `if (ActiveControl = Edit1) or (ActiveControl = Edit2) or .... then ...` and still `ActiveControl` would be used to inject messages

Comment: You could use this instead: `if (ActiveControl is TEdit) then TEdit(ActiveControl).Text ...;`